# Five star module in drupal 7 for anonymous users

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, fivestar

I am creating a content type which has fivestar_rating field, i want the authenticated and anonymous users to vote (rate) this content, when the authenticated users rate that content and then change it, the module calculate it as one vote, but when anonymous users try to rate several time, the module calculate every rate as new rate (vote) which allow any anonymous user vote many times on the same article to increase or decrease the rates.

is there a way to prevent anonymous user from rating more than one in a period of time, depending on the ip or browser? i am using Drupal 7.9, and the fivestar module 7.x-2.0-alpha1

Answer (score 2):

Go to this path in your drupal administration area.

admin > config > search > votingapi

You will have first option to select anonymous rollover time. In that option you can change duration of voting period of anonymous votes.